# Can getBestProvider ever return null?

Tags: java, android

In the following code snippet:

```
 Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
 Criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
 criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
 criteria.setBearingRequired(false);        
 criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
 criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);         
 String provider = DP.lm.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
```

I've tried to keep the criteria as broad as possible to get any GPS location provider available at all. I need to detect the case when none are available even then.

How can this be handled? Will the getBestProvider call ever return null in such a case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getBestProvider%28android.location.Criteria,%20boolean%29) says that:

> Returns the name of the provider that best meets the given criteria.
>   Only providers that are permitted to be accessed by the calling
>   activity will be returned. If several providers meet the criteria, the
>   one with the best accuracy is returned. If no provider meets the
>   criteria, the criteria are loosened in the following sequence: 
>      power requirement, accuracy, bearing, speed, altitude
>
> Note that the requirement
>   on monetary cost is not removed in this process.

So it is still possible that you cant find a provider that fulfills all your requirements. In this case, null is returned. This is not in the documentation, but I can valid it from my personal experience.

In order to avoid that, you can address a Provider directly, if the method getBestProvider returns null. So you have a backup.

Comment: Is there a way to detect if that particular, say GPS_LOCATION, is disabled (through the Settings > Location and Security)?